# How to install ta-lib library in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ta-lib

I am using this command

```
!pip install TA-Lib
```

But I am facing this error:

```
Collecting TA-Lib
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.28.tar.gz (357 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from TA-Lib) (1.23.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: TA-Lib
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for TA-Lib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for TA-Lib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
Failed to build TA-Lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for TA-Lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How to solve this?